# Change Auto Layout from wCompact hRegular to wAny hAny

Tags: swift, autolayout

I built iOS app with `wCompact hRegular`
but now I want to change that to `wAny hAny`
but when I do that the components disappear "buttons, labels, text fields..etc" from main.storyboard

what can I do to show and edit these components in `wAny hAny` position

Comment: It is the default behaviour of the size class, if you designed the UI for wCompact hRegular size class then if you change the size class you will not able to see the contents. For that if you want to change the size class to wAny hAny then make a copy of storyboard and then change the size class to wAny hAny and then copy and paste the contents/ViewControllers one by one from wCompact hRegular size class storyboard to wAny hAny size class storyboard.

Comment: As far as i know, No, there is no way to see the contents of two size classes at the same time. Size classes concept is came into picture only to make separate designs for different kind of devices in size.

Comment: You can try one easy trick, just select all the ViewControllers, Copy them all, change the size class to wAny hAny and then delete all the ViewControllers by selecting all and then just paste the ViewControllers which you have copied from the wCompact and hRegular size class. You can make a copy of storyboard if you afraid of loosing all the hard work you did to set that creepy constraints.